# how to set border color on textbox focus using javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

In my form five textboxes ..when click on textbox its border color has to be changed.(on textbox focus event the border color will get change)

Comment: Why with javascript? If you're not going to support IE7 or less then this could be done with CSS only.

Comment: Either by this: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_focus.asp or: http://buildinternet.com/2009/01/changing-form-input-styles-on-focus-with-jquery/ or: http://forums.asp.net/t/1134964.aspx/1

Comment: Please check below link http://forums.asp.net/t/1424739.aspx/1 Happy coding!!!

Comment: try this as suggested by Brian Mains: http://buildinternet.com/2009/01/changing-form-input-styles-on-focus-with-jquery/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Giri check this it help you

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeBorderColor(id)
{
 document.getElementById(id).style.border = "1px solid #ff0000";
  }
</script>

</head>

 <body>
 <input type="text" name="txtTest" id="txtTest" onclick="changeBorderColor(this.id)"/>
 </body>
```

This code for one textbox pass parameter in function

Comment: thanks for all your comments:)i got it....heartly thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

Just take a really simple DHTML approach:

```
<div id="textbox1" onfocus='changeBorderColor()'></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function changeBorderColor(){
var color=rgb(50,100,150);
document.getElementById("textbox1".style.border-color:" + color;
}
 </script>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

```
input {
border: 1px solid black;
margin-top: 150px;
margin-left: 100px;

height: 45px;
width: 300px;
padding: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;

font-size: 30px;

transition:.2s linear;
-webkit-transition:.2s linear;
-moz-transition:.2s linear;
}

input:focus {
outline: none;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px #61C5FA;
border-color: #61C5FA;
}
```

Comment: Hehe..any reason to downvote .?